# Problems with enhanced features in -regex of utility "find"

Tags: macos, bash

For example, this doesn't find the file:

```
: > 12; basename $(find -E . -regex '^(.*)(\d{2})' -print 2>/dev/null)
```

But this does:

```
basename $(find -E . -regex '^(.*)([0-9]{2})' -print 2>/dev/null)
```

At the same time, for example:

```
echo -e '12\nabc\n456' | grep -E -e '^(\d{3})'
```

works quite well, though seemingly uses the same `regcomp()`.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: Newer OS X `grep` use a `BSD` code base, not `GNU grep`. The `-E` option is a mosh of `POSIX ERE and PCRE` and I believe exclusive to OS X. `find` uses `BRE` and `ERE` and the `\d` character class is invalid.

Comment: @fd0 **Best comment!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ENHANCED FEATURES` is not available in the current implementation of `find`, as in the compiled version of `find` `REG_ENHANCED` flag is non passed (See `regex(3`) and https://opensource.apple.com/source/shell_cmds/shell_cmds-187/find/main.c).

Answer (score 1):

It appears there is a bug in the native MacOS find in which its `-regex` option does not correctly handle any of the Shortcuts described in `man re_format`. The following command seems to work:

```
find -E . -regex '^(.*)([[:digit:]]{2})' -print
```

This slightly simpler variant also seems to work:

```
find -E . -regex '.*[[:digit:]]{2}' -print
```

In short, `grep -E` and `find`s `-regex` option don't seem to handle regular expressions in exactly the same way.

Comment: @Erik Fuller, I think it's about something different, as well as the `gfind . -regextype 'egrep' -regex '^(.*)(\d{2})' -print 2>/dev/null` does not work

Comment: It's possible gfind has the same bug.
In any case there seems to be a viable workaround.

Comment: the problem is that drops out the whole class of "enhanced basic and enhanced extended REs". In this case it is not clear why "egrep" is working properly, because it also uses the same `regcomp ()`

Comment: It drops out some of the extended REs, but not all of them; the `[[:digit:]]` construct described in this answer does not seem to work in `find` without `-E`.

Comment: Not extended REs, but "enhanced basic and enhanced extended REs"

Comment: Whatever they're called, the find command's treatment of regular expressions seems to mishandle `\` characters. It might be calling the same library, but it might not be calling it the same way. In any case, the workaround I mentioned seems to work fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46096/discussion-between-cave-canem-and-eirik-fuller).

Comment: Eirik, let's continue here: [link] (https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46096/discussion-between-cave-canem-and-eirik-fuller)