# Why does command "find -iregex" work but "find -regex" with case insensitive flag "(?i)" doesn't?

Tags: macos, command-line, zsh

According to the man pages we should be able to use regex with the native `find` command like so:

```
find -E /Volumes/complete -regex "(?i).*frontline.*"
```

However it fails. I have tried quite a few variations which have also failed.

```
find -E /Volumes/complete -regex "\.*frontline.*\i"
find -E /Volumes/SeedDrive/complete -regex "(?i:.*frontline.*)" 
find: -regex: (?i:.*frontline.*): repetition-operator operand invalid
find -E /Volumes/SeedDrive/complete -regex "(\?i:.*frontline.*)"
find  /Volumes/SeedDrive/complete -regex "*[fF]rontline.*"
```

**Don't understand why but single quotes does work:**

```
find -E /Volumes/SeedDrive/complete -regex '.*[fF]rontline.*'
```

finds "frontline" or "Frontline"

Problem is I also have files that contain FRONTLINE, Frontline, frontline.

`man find` says:

> The options are as follows:
>
> ```
>  -E      Interpret regular expressions followed by -regex and -iregex
>          primaries as extended (modern) regular expressions rather than
>          basic regular expressions (BRE's).  The re_format(7) manual page
>          fully describes both formats.
> ```

`man re-format` says"

> Inline Options (available for enhanced extended REs only)
> Like the inline literal mode mentioned above, other options can be switched
> on and off for part of a RE.  ‘(?o..)’ will turn on the options specified
> in o.. (one or more options characters; see below), while ‘(?-o..)’ will
> turn off the specified options, and ‘(?o1..-o2..)’ will turn on the first
> set of options, and turn off the second set.
>
> ```
>  The available options are:
>
>        i      Turning on this option will ignore case during matching, while
>               turning off will restore case-sensitive matching.  If
>               REG_ICASE was specified to regcomp(), this option can be use
>               to turn that off.
> ```

...

> The scope of the option change begins immediately following the right
> parenthesis, but up to the end of the enclosing subexpression (if any).
> Thus, for example, given the RE ‘(fu(?i)bar)baz’, the ‘fu’ portion matches
> case sensitively, ‘bar’ matches case insensitively, and ‘baz’ matches case
> sensitively again (since is it outside the scope of the subexpression in
> which the inline option was specified).
>
> ```
>  The inline options syntax can be combined with the non-capturing
>  parenthesized subexpression to limit the option scope to just that of the
>  subexpression.  Then, for example, ‘fu(?i:bar)baz’ is similar to the
>  previous example, except for the parenthesize subexpression around
>  ‘fu(?i)bar’ in the previous example.
> ```

Comment: As it says, the inline options are "available for **enhanced** extended REs only", and `find -E` only supports regular (non-enhanced) extended REs. The `/.../i` version didn't work because that's not really RE syntax -- that's the syntax some languages use for *surrounding* an RE, but not part of the RE itself. The `"*[fF]rontline.*"` version didn't work because you forgot the "." at the beginning of the RE.

Comment: I didn't try it, but perhaps adding the option `-regextype posix-extended` helps.

Comment: @user1934428 Yes for GNU find (`brew install findutils`) valid types are ‘findutils-default’, ‘ed’, ‘emacs’, ‘gnu-awk’, ‘grep’, ‘posix-awk’, ‘awk’, ‘posix-basic’, ‘posix-egrep’, ‘egrep’, ‘posix-extended’, ‘posix-minimal-basic’, ‘sed’. MacOS installed `find` does not have this option.

Comment: Why don't you install the gnutools on the Mac? Most of them are more handy than the BSD ones, and you can have both of them in parallel, if you are worried of breaking existing scripts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To find all files, run:

```
find /Volumes/SeedDrive/complete -iregex ".*frontline.*"
```

Note that I'm using the `-iregex` option to match the expression in a case-insensitive manner.

### Down the rabbit hole of regular expressions

Regular expressions come in [two flavors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_basic_and_extended):

1. Basic (or obsolete), originally supported by `ed`.
2. Extended (or modern), supported by `egrep` and, when specifying the `-E` option, by `find` and `sed`. Extended regular expressions can also be used with `bash` when using the [`=~` operator](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Conditional-Constructs.html).

But there's more: as explained in `man re_format`, **the regular expression syntax can be enhanced to support "additional features"**:

> When the `REG_ENHANCED` flag is passed to one of the `regcomp()` variants, additional features are activated

`(?i)` is an example of such an additional feature, called **inline option**, which is available for *enhanced* extended regular expressions only. When used, the subexpression after `(?i)` is matched insensitively. For example, given the regular expression `fu(?i)bar`, the "fu" portion would match case sensitively while "bar" would match case insensitively.

Unfortunately, this is where things get blurry, *because it's up to the command you use to internally pass that flag to the `regcomp()` family of functions and support those additional features*.

For example, `egrep` supports the additional features:

```
$ ls
fuBAR    fubar
$ ls | egrep -E 'fu(?i)bar'
fuBAR
fubar
```

while `find` doesn't seem to support them:

```
$ ls
fuBAR    fubar
$ find -E . -regex '.*fu(\?i)bar'
$
```

### Why do your other commands fail?

`find -E /Volumes/complete -regex "(?i).*frontline.*"` tries to use enhanced regular expressions, which are not supported by `find`.

`find -E /Volumes/complete -regex "\.*frontline.*\i"` escapes the first `.`, which makes the first character of the expression a literal `.`. This will never match, because all lines returned by `find` start with the path you specified, namely `/Volumes/complete`, that is, the first character is `/`, not `.`.

`find -E /Volumes/SeedDrive/complete -regex "(?i:.*frontline.*)"` tries to use enhanced regular expressions, which are not supported by `find`.

`find -E /Volumes/SeedDrive/complete -regex "(\?i:.*frontline.*)"` tries to use enhanced regular expressions, which are not supported by `find`.

`find  /Volumes/SeedDrive/complete -regex "*[fF]rontline.*"` is missing a `.` at the beginning of the regular expression. The use of double quotes is not the culprit.

Comment: I don't think `(?i)` is an ERE feature, I think it's PCRE.

Comment: You're right, `(?i)` is not an ERE feature (but an *enhanced* ERE feature), and it is definitely a PCRE feature (see http://www.pcre.org/current/doc/html/pcre2syntax.html#SEC16). I've expanded my answer to make that clear.

Comment: For posterity.... ENHANCED FEATURES is not available in the current implementation of find https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/255619/40153